# Saving machine learning pipeline and results best practices

Tags: model-selection, scikit-learn

I've been thinking about how best to save tests I've done with certain preprocessing, hyperparameters etc. Obviously, I could just pickle/joblib every model I create, but I want an easy way to see exactly how I've handled certain aspects of the pipeline (i.e. did I do any dimensionality reduction, how did I handle missing data, which specific features did I use etc.) and what sort of results I got (in CV, on test set etc.). I feel like pickling an entire sklearn Pipeline could help, but then I'd find it rather difficult to easily read exactly what I'd done. So, my current thought is to create a spreadsheet with every step I'm concerned about and write a new line to this after every test. But I feel like there must be a better way. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't using a (or many) jupyter notebook help you here?

Comment: You could use a `.yml` file to specify the experiment and read in and store the file as part of the pipeline. The `.yml` file could specify what pre-processing to do (or point to a function that contains the require pre-processing) and any meta parameters.

Comment: jupyter notebooks would work, but make it difficult for me to compare and contrast the number of different pipelines I'll have. Same with .yml. The difficulty is I have quite a few subsets of features I'd like to try, several different ways of handling missing data (not all as simple as "median" - so I've had to name them). That's why a spreadsheet seemed to make the most sense - easy to read.

Comment: `git branch`???

Comment: Would I be able to record scores with git branch?